# Zebra Striped table using XML and XSLT

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I have looked at many posts on the StackOverflow site, and while I have gained some insight as to how to do the zebra striping, no post exhibits a complete example of how to implement it.

I am just learning to use XSLT, so I am certain it is because there is a larger picture I am missing.

my XML table and the section of XSL are included below.

I have ommited all of the data an other tags above this, but have included the parent tags.

XML

```
 <chapter>
     <section>
         <table-c>
             <tr> <td>Adept        </td> <td>spell-caster   </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Archers      </td> <td>warrior        </td>  </tr>
             <tr> <td>Bard         </td> <td>specialist     </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Barbarian    </td> <td>warrior        </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Cavalier     </td> <td>warrior        </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Cleric       </td> <td>spellcaster    </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Druid        </td> <td>spellcaster    </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Healer       </td> <td>spellcaster    </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Jumper       </td> <td>specialist     </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Martialist   </td> <td>warrior        </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Necromancer  </td> <td>spell-caster   </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Paladin      </td> <td>warrior        </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Ranger       </td> <td>warrior        </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Rogue        </td> <td>specialist     </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Sniper       </td> <td>specialist     </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Sorcerer     </td> <td>spellcaster    </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Swashbuckler </td> <td>warrior        </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Witch        </td> <td>spellcaster    </td> </tr>
             <tr> <td>Wizard       </td> <td>spellcaster    </td> </tr>
          </table-c>
    </section>
 </chapter>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:template match="table-c">
<!-- Table is center justified -->

  <table style="margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:1em;
        margin-bottom:1em;
        ">

<xsl:for-each select="tr">      
  <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:blue;</xsl:attribute>
      <tr>          
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </tr>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I just don't know how to implement the attribute once its created.(I'm not even sure I am creating it correctly).

This particular code causes the xsl parser to stop with an error.

My XML file was looking good until I put in those lines between the for-each tags.

I cannot use a CSS nth child option, because when I do, it effects every other table setup in the xsl file. I need to be able to apply different styling to a variety of tables, so when I get the method of striping working I will apply that method to different templates.

Unless someone knows how to confine css style-sheet methods to individual xsl templates. That would be fantastic, but I have not found anything on the internet so far indicating that it can be done.

Comment: Don't tell us you are getting an error without telling us what the error is. It's ridiculous to expect us to work it out without that information. Downvoting for that reason.

Comment: That was the error. Literally. The error was "xsl parser error". Pretty much a blank browers screen otherwise. No help whatsoever.

Comment: Running your XSLT code in the browser isn't the best way of debugging it, especially if you are inexperienced. But some browsers have better diagnostics in the developer console than others. You shouldn't care what's on the user screen at this point, it's what's on the developer console that's interesting.

Comment: Developer Console??????????

Comment: Oh dear, we really are starting from square one. Varies from one browser to another, but there's generally a menu item or icon called something like "tools" or "develop". It's your lifeline. Having said that, I wouldn't advise writing XSLT for the browser until you've got further in your XSLT learning curve, because the diagnostics are so poor in comparison with server-side tools. Ideally install oXygen or another XML IDE.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found the winning answer.

```
<xsl:template match="table-c">
<!-- Table is center justified -->

  <table style="margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-top:1em;
        margin-bottom;1em;
        ">

    <xsl:for-each select="tr">
      <tr>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">
            <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:cyan</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:gray</xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>

  </table>

</xsl:template>
```

For all those just learning XSLT and need a detailed explanation of what is going on...well here it is:

I assume you already know about how to apply basic templates in XSL. If not, then go to the W3C SCHOOLS website and learn that.

The key to getting alternating color rows (aka zebra stripes), is to wrap the row/decision if odd or even code inside a for-each loop. This loops through each row of the table and makes a decision about the row position on each iteration of the loop.
The breakthrough for me, was discovering that the xsl:choose/xsl:when code figures out what row its on while its inside the row. Notice the  is the last line before the closing , which is after the closing .
After the choose code has figured out what row its on and set the style accordingliy, THEN that style is applied to the row.
Then, the for-each loop move on to the next row, and the choose/when code starts all over again to figure out what row its on.

While I kept my example simple, what you don't see is that my xsl file has several table templates, and I was able to take this code and apply all manor of styling with it to various other table templates.

For some reason the creators of XSL did not include a if/then or if/else-if/else with their xsl:if. If you want that type of function, then you have to use that crazy choose/when they came up with.

Comment: "If not, then go to the W3C SCHOOLS website and learn that." (a) The w3schools web site has nothing to do with W3C. (b) it can be a handy place to look up things you already know for quick reference, but as a place to learn about concepts, it leaves an awful lot to be desired. Get yourself a decent book.

Comment: "... creators of XSL did not include a if/else-if/else with their xsl:if". If you added an xsl:then to xsl:if you would end up with something remarkably similar to xsl:choose.

Comment: You can simplify your code in XSLT 2.0 to `<tr style="background-color: {if (position() mod 2 = 1) then 'gray' else 'cyan'}">`. Even in XSLT 1.0, you can simplify it by moving the common parts of the xsl:attribute instruction outside the xsl:choose.

Comment: That method looks very appealing, so a question: in other posts many responders suggest using the css tr: nth child (odd) {background-color: some_color} instead of trying to loop or do other code. My frustration with the answers to those posts are that they never show enough code to know WHERE to put that in the xsl file. So with the example above, is there where the nth child {    } would go?

Comment: Be patient and do lots of reading, and practice with simple tasks. If you ask a question about fixing your central heating boiler when you don't really understand how the heating system is supposed to work, you aren't going to understand the answers you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS like:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {  background: #ccc  }
tr:nth-child(odd) {  background: #fff  }
```

**Update**: Sorry, missed that, maybe try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="chapter/section/table-c/tr">      
  <xsl:if test="(position() mod 2) != 1">
    <xsl:attribute style="background-color:blue">make_blue</xsl:attribute>
      <tr style="make_blue">            
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </tr>
 </xsl:if>
<xsl:for-each>
```

Code based from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254777/xslt-how-to-style-conditional-odd-even-rows)

Comment: I would love to, but like I mentioned above you have not posted a complete enough example of how I would implement that. Can you show me where I would put that in the XSL file. Can you include more surrounding code. I did try that earlier, but it effects every table template in the xsl file.

Comment: Thank you. I have made some edits to my original xsl file in the original post. I was getting parsing errors because of some serious syntax mistakes not related to my question in the post. Anyone looking at this post will see those mistakes in the code posted back with a suggestion by Chris Happy. Also, there was an extra </xsl:attribute> tag before the </xsl:if> so I removed that. After correcting those syntax mistakes the file parsed, but my table was still plain with no striping. The next mistake can be seen in the post back that I have my <xsl:attribute.... tag completely misconfigured.

Comment: The correct (and now working) syntax produces a table with only every other (odd) row showing, all with blue background, so my entire table is now blue with only half the rows in it. I must be on the right track. now to figure out how to get the rest of my rows.

Comment: @Frustrated-Me: "you have not posted a complete enough example". I'm sorry, but you can't expect to get much value from posting questions on StackOverflow unless you have done enough basic reading about the technologies you are using to enable you to understand the answers. We can tell you here how to change a light-bulb, but we can't teach you to drive a car.

Comment: Not sure how my example is not "complete enough". It's solved now, and the final answer is contained in the same code example I originally posted, except the code needed to be rearranged. I mean the person below Kai Weber got it. If I had checked back sooner I could have just copy/paste that persons answer and that would have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is basically correct, just the position of the `<xsl:if>` is wrong. You need to apply the attribute to every second `<tr>` that you generate in the output, so the `<xsl:if>` and the `<xsl:attribute>` that belongs to it have to be put below the `<tr>` output element:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tr">      
  <tr>          
    <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:blue;</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you have

```
<xsl:for-each select="tr">
    <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 1">
        <tr>
    ...
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
<xsl:for-each>
```

you get a kind of filter function on the original `<tr>` elements: Only every second `<tr>` from the source document will be processed and put into the result document. This is clearly not what you wanted. You need to put every source `<tr>` into the result document, and add an attribute to every second `<tr>`. That is why you have to move the `<xsl:if>` below the `<tr>`.

Comment: If only I would have check back an hour ago. Your reply would have saved me a lot of hair pulling. As I posted answering my own question, placing the test inside the row and the for-each outside the row did the trick. Unfortunate I never found another post that emphasized that.